# flac to "stereo mp3" not "joint stereo" using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, flac, stereo

After reading and trying contents of the post talking about flac to mp3 conversion, I didn't find the solution

I try this command again and again for converting flac to "stereo" mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f mp3 output.mp3
```

but the output is joint stereo
**I need a stereo output.**

Any help?
Cheers

Comment: Can you actually tell the difference, audibly?

Comment: Joint stereo is still stereo, just with improved efficiency (“fitting more sound in the same amount of data”) by using appropriate delta encoding for the second channel.

Comment: MediaInfo software shows some kind of difference between joint stereo and stereo file

Comment: @samsam114 Yes of course, joint stereo needs to be processed differently to get the two distinct channels.

Comment: Joint stereo is a different process, usually using mid-side difference, which is a perfectly sound [pardon the pun] way of differentiating audio by analysing the difference between left & right. For an mp3, if you can actually tell the difference between true stereo & mid-side, then power to your ears. I can't in 9 out of 10 cases & I'm a sound engineer ;)

Comment: actually, my algorithm exactly relies the differences between stereo and joint in bits.

Comment: I'm glad you guys cleared this up.  I thought "joint stereo" was music you listen to while stoned.

Comment: @samsam114 If your algorithm relies on a bit-perfect audio stream, why use a lossy compression like MP3? With good encoders, joint stereo offers superior quality. That’s why it’s the default.

Comment: @DanielB that's an order ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joint stereo is enabled by default, so use

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -joint_stereo 0 output.mp3
```

Comment: I've also used above command, but the output is still joint stereo

Comment: Show the console output of your command.

Comment: Input #0, flac, from 'input.flac':
Duration: 00:02:55.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 754 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0:Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz,stereo,s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
size=    6871kB time=00:02:55.85 bitrate= 320.1kbits/s
video:0kB audio:6870kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 0.015479%

Comment: How are you checking for the channel mode and content?

Comment: with media Info. I didn't find sth more exact. Do you suggest sth else?

Comment: My command works here. Which version of ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg version 2.8.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)

Comment: Any idea Mulvya?

Comment: Try with a newer version.

Comment: I will try it buddy and will let you know the progress

Comment: GREEEEEEAAAT :) it worked buddy. Thanks you Mulvya 2^256 time :)